# Creation of sample data in database tool @ sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, database, sample

I need a database tool where i can easily add information to it.

Example:

I have 2 tables, customers and invoices. The database tool must show me input fields of the customer and invoices. invoice has a foreign key to customer. The input fields of invoices must have a dropdown where i can select the customer so i won't have to copy paste the ID of the customer.

Answer (score 1):

The tags on your question suggest you may be creating test data. Have you considered a tool like RedGate's [Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter the sample data manually (that's how I understood your question), **Microsoft Access** sounds like the tool of choice here:

Create a new Access DB and link to the SQL Server tables. Enter the customers directly in Table view. For the invoices, use the wizard to create a form, then create a combobox that references to the customers table.